# My optifine zoom is off centre

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-optifine

When I was playing the game before with optifine, I could use the zoom and it would be perfectly centre when I fell. But for some reason it has changed due to my friends asking me to add the scripts for RLCraft. Now it goes slightly behind making it impossible to line up any water jumps. Any fixes?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Modded Minecraft technical support is off-topic here.

Comment: You could ask in some forum for those mods you use instead, but then you'll need to give more details, like what kinds of script those are (or even direct links to them).